# Processing Strings Using a For Loop

Tags: python, iteration

I need to write a function that counts the number of times characters from one string occur in another.

This is what I have so far,

```
def occurrences(text1, text2):
"""Return the number of times characters from text1 occur in text2

occurrences(string, string) -> int
"""
count = 0
#setup = set('text1')
for text1 in text2:
    if text1 == text2:
        count += 1
return count
```

I don't understand how to compare the strings given that they will be randomly generated. I know I need to look at each character in the second argument and see if it is in the first argument.

Comment: Do you mean, the number of characters that are in `text2`?

Comment: Can you give some example inputs and outputs?

Comment: What should be output for `text1 = "ABC"`, and `text2 = "ABABAB"`?

Comment: The output should be 7.

Comment: @SunshineTS Don't you mean 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know I need to look at each character in the second argument and see if it is in the first argument.

That's exactly what you need to write:

```
for character in text2:
    if character in text1:
        count += 1
```